# Gazebo crashes when spawning a robot with urdf

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, robot, spawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm looking forward to use ROS Indigo with the fresh released Ubuntu 14.04. Gazebo is starting fine but instantly crashes when spawning a robot via service call:

```
(indigo) alex@ThinkPad-T440p:~/hector$ rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file `rospack find baxter_description`/urdf/baxter.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model baxter
spawn_model script started
[INFO] [WallTime: 1400760484.921875] [0.000000] Loading model xml from file
[INFO] [WallTime: 1400760484.922486] [0.000000] Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[INFO] [WallTime: 1400760484.924802] [0.000000] Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
```

Lets Gazebo crash without any message:

```
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 14649, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/alex/.ros/log/cdde1b80-e1a0-11e3-ab05-5c514ff707c4/gazebo-1.log].
log file: /home/alex/.ros/log/cdde1b80-e1a0-11e3-ab05-5c514ff707c4/gazebo-1*.log
```

I've just tested it with Gazebo 2.2.2 (sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-ros) using "empty_world" and the Baxter robot urdf (see gazebosim.org /Tutorials/1.9/Using_roslaunch_Files_to_Spawn_Models, sry not enough Karma for links ;)).

Has anybody encountered this issue too?

kind regards,
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168156/gazebo-crashes-when-spawning-a-robot-with-urdf./) by [a_stumpf](https://answers.ros.org/users/18251/a_stumpf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [a_stumpf](https://answers.ros.org/users/18251/a_stumpf/) on 2014-06-02**:
It's still a big issue. Hasn't anybody else this issue with Ubuntu 14.04 and indigo?

**Comment by [fhurlbrink](https://answers.ros.org/users/18571/fhurlbrink/) on 2014-06-13**:
I have the same problem!

**Comment by [4dahalibut](https://answers.ros.org/users/19021/4dahalibut/) on 2014-07-11**:
I think this problem might have to deal with it being a thinkpad. I have the same problem with Hydro and 12.04 and both Gazebo 1.9 and Gazebo 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The root cause seems to be urdf library incompatibilities. The developers are aware of the issue (https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/4633).

I'm also looking forward to a fix but for now it seems the workaround is to use a source-built version of gazebo. See the June 8, 3am comment from jonbinney on that thread.

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2014-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe it is a solution for another URDF-parsing problem, but you may try adding

```
# fix for liburdf segfault
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

to your .bashrc .

Hope it doesn't break anything else in your system :) I'm happy with this solution so far.

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2014-06-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2014-06-18**:
To see whether it is really a URDF parsing issue, you may try `gzsdf print myrobot.urdf` . If it crashes, then liburdf is the responsible one.

**Comment by [a_stumpf](https://answers.ros.org/users/18251/a_stumpf/) on 2014-06-20**:
Thanks for your suggestion but it didn't work in this case.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-02-13**:
This solved the segfault-issue for me. (Indigo on Ubuntu14.04)

**Comment by [Horse-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/22198/horse-man/) on 2019-08-30**:
This worked for me with ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04